# PDO connection bind value not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not what is the issue with this code, i'm trying to bind value but it is not working properly. I'm getting

> INSERT INTO menucategory (menu_type,menu_order,menu_status) VALUES (?,?,?)

as it is

Here is my code

```
<?php 

class RDBConnection{
private $host,$user,$password,$dbname;
public $dbh,$sth;
function __construct(){
   $this->host="localhost";
   $this->user="user";
   $this->password="pass";
   $this->dbname="zczc";
}
// connect method create connection
function connect(){
    try{
  $this->dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->user,$this->password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  //$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
// disconnect method disconnect connection created
function disconnect(){
    $this->dbh=null;
}
// insert
function inserMenu($menu){
    $this->sth=$this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO menucategory (menu_type,menu_order,menu_status) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $this->sth->bindParam(1, $menu[0]);
    $this->sth->bindParam(2, $menu[1]);
    $this->sth->bindParam(2, $menu[2]);
    $this->sth->execute();
   return true;
}
}
?>
```

I referred it from here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#118975

Comment: what exactly is the problem? are you getting an empty data or something? is your query not working or something?

Comment: why di you comment PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION out? It would have given you a clue

Comment: It is displaying query itself. INSERT INTO menucategory (menu_type,menu_order,menu_status) VALUES (?,?,?) like this

Comment: Like i wrote in the first line